# With django, how can I retrieve if the user "likes" the article of other items?

Tags: django, blogs

I have 3 tables in my database, the first one is the "user" table with users' basic information, the second one is the "article" table, and the last one is the "user_like_article" table which store a record for a user and a article if the user likes the article.

For instance, if a user A like an article X, the the record in the "user_like_article" table will be like this: (A,X)

So now, I want to indicate whether the user, who has logged in, like a certain article in the article list I diplay. 
I have figure out a way. I first get the article list. After that, I get the list of article's id which the specific user likes. The other things work like the code below

```
for article in articles_to_diplay:
    if article in article_list_user_likes:
        article['like'] = True
```

This method works, but somehow I think it is too expensive. Displaying "like" button is just a little part of my project, but it is indeed very common. Facebook, Twitter, blogs, "like" is in widespread use.

Is there any way less expensive to accomplish this feature?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post the models definitions, so we know exactly what types of relations there are..

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite simple to use some nice looking API, since we check query against logged in user object, so we need to inject `is_liked` method for each article object.

Also you can use `ManyToManyField` field for `Article` model, instead creating additional table (unless you're using some extra data, then let me know, so I can modify the answer accordingly.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().prefetch_related('likes')
    for a in articles:
        a.is_liked = (request.user in a.likes.all())

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'articles': articles})
```

Comment: thank you so much, inject a method "is_like" and use "prefetch_related" should be much better !